# Ajax pagination works only first and third time

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm using ajax-based pagination, heres the markup

```
<div id="portfolio-thumbs">
        <ul id="portfolio-destaque">
     HERE GOES MY LOOP AND CONTENT , some LI's with thumbs and stuff   
                        </ul></div>
                <div id="pagi-container">
                    <div id="paginar">
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>  
            </div>
</div>
```

then, i use this jquery so it loads content inside `#portfolio-thumbs` and pagination links inside `#pagi-container`:

```
  $('#paginar > a').on('click',  function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#portfolio-thumbs').html('Loading...');
        jQuery('#portfolio-thumbs').load(link+' #portfolio-destaque');
        jQuery('#pagi-container').load(link+' #paginar');

    });
```

Well, when i click `> Next Page` for the first time:

it loads `page/2` ok, inside `#portfolio-thumbs` goes the looped posts and the markup stays the same

except for the `< previous page` link that is added inside `#pagi-container`

If I click again, the jquery/ajax does not work, and loads full `page/3`, reloading browser's window.. If, in `page/3` I click `<previous page` or `> next-page` ajax works ok again.... Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

@kennypu in stackoverflow saved my life with this:

t's because you're changing the contents of `#paginar`, so what happens is the event on the links are getting cleared. depending on your jquery version, you can either use .live() or add the even to the #pagi-container instead:

```
$('#pagi-container').on('click','#paginar > a',function() {... }
```

my finished code is like this:

```
  $('#pagi-container').on('click','#paginar > a',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        $('#portfolio-thumbs').html('Aguarde, por favor...');
        $('#portfolio-thumbs').load(link+' #portfolio-destaque');
        $('#pagi-container').load(link+' #paginar');

    });
```

thanks kennypu!